# Http failure response for (unknown url) - Angular Universal on Docker

Tags: angular, docker, universal, nginx-reverse-proxy, server-side-rendering

I have the following setup:

Four services in **docker-compose.yml**: `my_nginx`, `my_client`, `my_api` and `my_db`.

1. I use `my_nginx` as a proxy pass to reach `my_client:8000` and `my_api:8001`
   (both are Node.js).
2. `my_client` is the Angular application which has server side
   rendering.
3. `my_api` is a node app, which gets data from `my_db`.

Then, in my windows `hosts` file I have the same host names I defined in the `my_nginx` config server blocks:

```
`127.0.0.1 my-app.local api.my-app.local`
```

so they can be accessed by host name.

Next, in my angular application I have the api url defined in each environment file, so for the local dev environment it is `http://api.my-app.local`.

It works perfectly fine when the api request comes from within the browser. But when the request is initiated server side, from the `my_client` container, I get a very long (many rows) error, but the gist of it (and the commonly used text I could find it by, searching Google) is: `message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error'`. However, the other questions I could find didn't answer my issue. They're either not server-rendered, or mentioning CORS or containers not having internet access.

I do allow any client from my api: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`, CORS is not an issue. Also, if I replaced `http://api.my-app.local` with `http://some-real-website.com`, then the request works, it goes through, I'm just not receiving appropriate data because it's not my api, but the point is that my containers are able to access the internet. Jumping into the `my_client` container and `ping api.my-app.local` works (showing 127.0.0.1, don't know if this means anything). I don't know why that works, while pinging with `http://...` doesn't, but I can't replace `http://api.my-app.local` with `api.my-app.local` in my Angular app, because then it would make the request to itself, like: `http://my-app.local/api.my-app.local`.

And lastly, if I ping `http://api.my-app.local` then I get `unknown host`. Don't know why, as far as the container is concerned, `http://api.my-app.local` is on the internet, right?. I mean, I expect things to work the same, no matter who/what/where from tries to access, like:

1. someone/something accesses the url `http://api.my-app.local` (can be me/browser, can be a container, whatever)
2. In the end, that is captured by the host (Windows in my case) and the hosts file redirects it to `127.0.0.1`
3. which then reaches the `my_nginx` container
4. which recognises the server name `api.my-app.local`
5. and proxies it to `my_api` container.

Should be very simple.

**EDIT:**

Docker version: 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139) stable

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my_nginx:
    container_name: my_nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    image: my_nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443' # SSL (not used on 'my-app.local')
    links:
      - my_api
      - my_client

  my_api:
    container_name: my_api
    build:
      context: ./node_api
    image: my_api
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    volumes:
      - ./node_api/app:/var/www/api.my-app.com
      - /var/www/api.my-app.com/node_modules
    links:
      - my_db
    depends_on:
      - my_db
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - api.my-app.local
    tty: true
    # command: ["pm2-docker", "pm2.config.json"] < moved to Dockerfile

  my_client:
    container_name: my_client
    build:
      context: ./node_client
    image: my_client
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./node_client/app:/var/www/my-app.com
      - /var/www/my-app.com/node_modules # Inside the container, use the node_modules installed there.
    links:
      - my_api
    tty: true
    command: ["pm2-docker", "pm2.config.json"]

  my_db:
    container_name: my_db
    build:
      context: ./mysql
    image: my_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - './_space/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
```

Nginx config api server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.my-app.local;

    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 4096M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_api:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And the one for the client is the same, except `server_name` and `proxy_pass` directives, of course. I don't know what `proxy_http_version`, `proxy_set_header` and `proxy_cache_bypass` are for, I just copied the config from an online example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yml you need to declare the alias for my_nginx and link for my_client:

```
my_nginx:
    networks:
        default:
            aliases:
                - api.my-app.local

my_client:
    links:
        - my_nginx
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the first option, but didn't help. Haven't tried the second one, but I guess it won't have a different result. I don't know what else I'm missing, I must be missing something more. I've edited the question to add the `docker-compose.yml` file, with the first option from your example added to it.

Comment: I just tested setting up a docker env with your docker-compose.yml. It seems to be working. Could you try running `docker-compose up --build`? After that, see if pinging the api from the client works: `docker exec -t my_client ping api.my-app.local`.

Comment: The ping works, now it doesn't say `127.0.0.1` anymore, it finds an actual IP. However, I get the same error when the app runs, when the node server makes the request for the api. Is `http://api.my-app.local` different somehow than `api.my-app.local`? Because `ping http://api.my-app.local` does say `unknown host`. Might there be something wrong with my docker for windows version? Or something weirdly wrong with my Windows PC... I've even tried resetting docker to factory defaults, but it didn't help.

Comment: You've already taken out of your time to help, but I've created a repo here https://github.com/MrCroft/docker-app. I'm only curious if it works for you, whenever you have some time. I've moved the pm2 command from docker-compose to Dockerfile, commented the `volumes` section in the `my_client` service and I do `npm install` in the container, so all that's needed is to run `docker-compose up` (the build will take a while), and add `127.0.0.1 my-app.local api.my-app.local` to the hosts file of the host operating system, of course.

Comment: Ohhh.. I see now. The problem is that the alias should be in your nginx container, not in the my_api container. That’s because the node container doesn’t listen to the http/https ports, but the nginx one does, and then redirects the request to the corresponding node container.